# Загрузка файла через SSH посредством php

Tags: php, ssh

Есть функция, через которую подгружаются файлы:

```
function img_load($url,$nm){
if (preg_match("/http/",$url)){
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$out = curl_exec($ch);      
$file = '/docs/domen.ru/pub/data/U7777/at/Script/pictures/'.$nm.'.jpg';
$img = file_put_contents($file, $out);
curl_close($ch); 
}
return $img;
}
```

Так функция работает! Но посредством SSH файлы сохраняет в корень!
Скажите, как это можно исправить, или есть метод подгрузки Файлов, а то получается, требуется использовать `chdir();`, что не очень удобно, ведь путь до папки очень длинный, и легко запутаться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'/docs/domen.ru/pub/data/U7777/at/Script/pictures/'.$nm.'.jpg'
```

Это полный путь на сервере? Полный путь от корня на диске попробуйте, узнайте у хостера, если не знаете.

Comment: хм!! интересная мысль есть полный путь!

Comment: Толковая и правильная мысль! Спасибо вам однозначно + @Roundik.
Я уже стал делать по-другому, но это намного проще, чем велосипед изобретать!  Еще раз спасибо!